# I create a jquery function but focus doesn't work properly in bootstrap input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input, focus

see the below code and fiddle. when I write something on skype and after finishing writing I hit the enter key of keyboard then it automatically focus the last input field.

I need to focus the next input field when hit the enter key from keyboard.
i.e. Write something in linkedin input field and hit the enter key then facebook input field will focus.

another example: Write something in facebook input field and hit the enter key then twitter input field will focus.

here the  [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/aoy5645d/)

Comment: it is because you are using a general identifier which is "input.enter" = last input. it is equal to last input because it is the last "input.enter" element that is added to the dom

Comment: please give me any solution.I also tried using next(). but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/h1hecocm/1/

When You do just:

```
$("input.enters").focus();
```

jQuery get **all input's** with class **enters** and set focus to **last one**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822160/after-redirecting-page-using-jquery-can-i-fill-an-input-field-on-new-page see this how can I do it?